# SonarQube Android-Lint repository does not contain all the android-lint official rules?

Tags: android, sonarqube, lint

In sonarqube  **Android-lint repository** i could find only **158 rules**,but there are **281 rules** in android-lint officially. Do you have any clues why the remaining **123 rules** are not available on **Sonarqube Lint repository ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The latest version of the plugin was released in 2015 & the version of Android Lint embedded in it is probably quite old now. Without a list of the missing rules, it's difficult to verity but it is likely that these rules were added since the latest plugin release.
>
> Note that the plugin is no longer maintained by SonarSource. It is a repository in search of a maintainer.

[This answer was was given by one of the sonarqube officials.](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sonarqube/e-ate8Bahfk/dPSYaSW7BQAJ) When I posted it on their official Google Group. It's a very relevant question so I re-posted it here.

For confirmation refer the below link you will find the discussion:

- [SonarQube: Android-Lint repository does not contain all the android-lint official rules](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/e-ate8Bahfk)

Comment: **Update:** I can read in the thread that _Orion Fields_ took over the project in May 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the new Android Lint Plugin for SonarQube - https://github.com/jvilya/sonar-android-plugin.

I'm using SonarQube heavily in my work. As a result, I suffer from incomplete support of Android Lint rules. One plugin is too old, another does work only via "external issues".

So I decided to wrote my own plugin that provides native SonarQube's experience to work with Android Lint issues.

Now it supports 313 rules (from Android Lint and Timber library).